# Should the security tag mention Security.SE?

Tags: discussion

Already, I see a few questions which, while they ***seem*** to be about the security aspects of IoT, are really just plain security questions, applicable also to non-IoT situations & devices.

Should the [security](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tag mention https://security.stackexchange.com/? It is quite likely that many posters are not aware of it, or did not think of it because, "hey, I have an IoT device".

Possibly even some extra code, to generate a pop-up when submitting a [security](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tagged question, to explain the difference between the sites and ask if the question should be migrated there? Or is that too much?

Comment: I say edit it (though I don't know if/when anyone will approve the edits - the rep needed is 750 so I assume it'll be moderator only at the moment). A popup might be a bit much though, but perhaps a migration target for Security SE could be useful if we get a lot of questions like that?

Comment: Sigh! I suspect that edititng it is the solution. It will mean a lot of edits, though. I for one will keep a text snippet handy to paste as a comment - over and over again :-)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it should be mentioned. I thing the security site and the dev board sites will be the main points of overlap and the places to watch out for scope issues.

Comment: +1 BUT, which dev board sites? If you port links, we can quote them when commenting posts